# Installing Postgres-XL with PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgres-xl, postgis-installation

**Problem**: I am trying to install Postgres-XL with PostGis enabled on a 3 node cluster. I managed to install Postgres-XL on 3 nodes with 1 GTM, 1 Co-ordinator & 1 Data Node. Now the problem is when I try to install the PostGis extension on DataNode it installs successfully but when I try to install it on Coordinator it gives me the following error:

```
[postgres@test_pg_coord postgis-2.3.2]$ psql -d test11 -q -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;' -p 30001
ERROR:  type "gidx" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE OPERATOR && (
  LEFTARG    = gidx,
  RIGHTARG   = geography,
  PROCEDURE  = overlaps_geog,
  COMMUTATOR = &&
)"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement
```

Do I need to just install PostGis on all datanodes & Coordinator or just datanodes?

Any help on the error and / or above question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to get it working with **PostGis 2.3.1**. So the issue is with **PostGis 2.3.2** version.

I think the new version **PostGis 2.3.2** is still not compatible with Postgres-XL.